# How to iterate over a vector in Rust without destroying it

Tags: rust

How do I iterate over a `Vec` in Rust without destroying the elements?

```
for i in v
{
    println!("{}", i);
}
```

Can I somehow make `i` a constant reference?

I attempted this, but obtained an error.

```
for &i in multipliers_vec
{
    println!("{}", i);
}
```

```
expected `i64`, found reference
```

Comment: iterate over `v.iter()`, e.g. `v.iter().for_each(|i| print!("{}", i));` or `for i in v.iter()`

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov Doesn't an iterator re-poses ownership of the container?

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant there's a difference between `.iter()` and `.iter_mut()` and `.into_iter()`.  The first two do not consume the `Vec`, but the 3rd does, and is the default of `for x in y`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you almost got it:

```rust
for i in &v {
    println!("{}", i);
}
```

Or, although less idiomatic:

```rust
for i in v.iter() {
    println!("{}", i);
}
```